# Exception occurs when i try to create instance of UserProfileManager

Tags: c#, sharepoint, exception

I am using UserProfileManager to get user profiles in sharepoint. I compiled the code on MOSS machine and then tried to run it on SP2010 machine but then it threw an exception that it couldnt find 'Microsoft.Office.Server' version=12.0.0.0 but now my question is why it is looking for MOSS assembly on SP2010 machine

Error which it throws is

```
  System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
'Microsoft.Office.Server, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
publicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the
file specified.File name: 'Microsoft.Office.Server, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
publicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should recreate you code for SharePoint Server (not Foundation!) 2010 assemblies. For this you should have SPS2010 and VS2010 on the same machine.

Comment: Hi Thanks for replying but Can you please explain it a little more